# Developers Option in Pebble App Settings

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I am following this [manual](http://www.sitepoint.com/pebble-watch-development-javascript/) and I don't have the Developers Option in my Pebble App Setting when I look at Application Manager. Any idea why is that and how I can find it? I have a Samsung Galaxy S6.
 `Pebble app > Settings > Developer Options` and tick `Enable Developer Connection`.
[image]
There's no such 3 lines for the app setting as shown in this [link.](https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/publishing-tools/developer-connection/)

Comment: Did my answer not help you? If you are still having issues, please let us know and someone will surely assist you

Comment: Hi Kenneth. The problem was I needed to factory reset the pebble because someone else in our lab was using it beforehand. After factory reset it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual you linked to seems to be the right set of steps.

The screenshot you posted though indicates you do not have a Pebble connected, which may be the root of the problem. I believe the developer option only appears if a Pebble watch is actually connected. Once its enabled, it will stay that way though.